# How to build a dynamic tree of arbitrary depth in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I need to build a tree with *n* number of children at each level and *t* number of levels. Each node will contain a value.

I can make a tree using a *node class* and then using multiple for loops for multiple levels. But how do I achieve this without for loops (how to do this recursively)?

I think I am making some obvious mistakes while using recursion. I start with one node (root) and some children and then do the following:

```py
class Tree():
   def __init__(self):
     self.children = []
     self.data = []

   def create_children(self, childNum):
     for num in range(childNum):
        self.children.append(Tree())

   def create_data(self, data):
        for val in data:
           self.data.append(val)

root = Tree()  # create root
root.create_data([0])
root.create_children(3)  # create branch 1 with n=3 children

for b1child in root.children:
   b1child.create_data([2]) # create data of each node
   # create branch 2 
   b1child.create_children(3) # create 3 children at each node

   for b2child in b1child.children:
      b2child.create_data([2])         # create branch 3
      b2child.create_children(3)

      for b3child in b2child.children:
        b3child.create_data([2])

# test children exists with value 
root.children[0].children[1].children[2].data
```

Comment: What values do the newly created child nodes get when you create them?

Comment: The values should come from another function

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to do this with a recursive method in your `Node` class. Something like this, though you'll need to add something to provide a value for each `Node` instance:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

    def create_children(self, num_children, depth):
        if depth == 0:                                     # base case
            return

        for i in range(num_children):
            child = Node()
            self.children.append(child)
            child.create_children(num_children, depth-1)   # recurse!
```

Your `Tree` code can then just create the root node and call `root.create_children(n, t)` (or maybe `t-1`, I'm not sure if the root should count as part of the depth).